# How order table after selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have URL API and i did group by "date".

But I would like to know how I can after I selected option from the data Importance its will order only the rows (and keep the date) by Importance.

Image how its order now:

http://prntscr.com/ebgodq

My code:

```
    var table = $(".top-table");
    var body = table.children("tbody");
    var regdate = /^(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})$/;

    $.get("http://api.tradingeconomics.com/calendar?c=guest:guest", function (data) {

        showData(data);

    });

    function showData (data) {

        //---Sort the data from the server
        data.sort(function (a, b) {

            return (new Date(a.Date)) - (new Date(b.Date));

        });

        var group = data.reduce(function (before, current) {

            var day = current.Date.replace(regdate, "$1");
            var hour = current.Date.replace(regdate, "$2");

            if (!before[day]) {

                before[day] = [];

            }

            current.Hour = hour;

            before[day].push(current);

            return before;

        }, {});

        for(var date in group) {

            body.append("<tr style='text-align: left;background: #fafafa;line-height: 35px;border-bottom: 2px solid #ff9d00;font-size: 13pt;font-weight: normal;'>" +
                    "<th width='50%'>" + date + "</th>" +
                    "<th width='12%'>Actual</th>" +
                    "<th width='12%'>Previous</th>" +
                    "<th width='12%'>Forecast</th>" +
                    "<th width='4%'></th></tr>");

            group[date].forEach(function(row){

                var rowA = parseInt(row.Actual) > 0 ?
                "<span style='color:red;'>" + noCommas(row.Actual) + "</span>" :
                "<span style='color:green;'>" + noCommas(row.Actual) + "</span>";

                var rowB = parseInt(row.Previous) > 0 ?
                "<span style='color:red;'>" + noCommas(row.Previous) + "</span>" :
                "<span style='color:green;'>" + noCommas(row.Previous) + "</span>";

                var rowC = parseInt(row.Forecast) > 0 ?
                "<span style='color:red;'>" + noCommas(row.Forecast) + "</span>" :
                "<span style='color:green;'>" + noCommas(row.Forecast) + "</span>";

                var Time = hourwithAMPM(row.Date);

                body.append("<tr style='border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;text-align: left;font-size: 12pt;font-weight: 300;line-height: 30px;'>" +
                        "<td><span class='im-" + row.Importance + "'>" + Time + "</span>" +
                        "<span style='margin: 0 10px 0;'><img src='/images/calendar/flags/" + noCommas(row.Country) + ".png' width='16' height='16' /></span>" +
                        "<span style='font-size: 11pt;color:#999999;font-weight: 600;word-spacing: -1px;margin: 0 5px 0;'>" + noCommas(row.Event) + "</span>"+
                        "<span style='color:#333333;'> " + noCommas(row.Reference) + "</span>" +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + rowA + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + rowB + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + rowC + "</td>" +
                        "<td><div class='arrow-down'></div></td>" +
                        "</tr>");

                body.append("<tr  class='showRow' style='display:none;'><td>yay!!!</td></tr>");

            });

        }

    }
```

Comment: You may use DataTables Table plug-in for jQuery to do so.

Comment: must be a way to do it only with the rows and not all, you maybe have any idea?

Comment: could you please  provide an image or description of the desired result. I don't understand what you mean by reorder and keep the date. isn't the date in a `th`? or is it in the first 'td'?

Comment: i mean keep the group "date" but only order the td`s to Importance.